# How to use IRawElementProviderSimple Interface in winforms .Net5.0

Tags: wpf, winforms, .net-core, accessibility, .net-5

Thanks in advance.

We have .Net5.0 WinForms projects, and we need to use an `IRawElementProviderSimple` interface in our.Net5.0 WinForms projects, .Net5.0 supports the `IRawElementProviderSimple` interface ([MSDN reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.provider.irawelementprovidersimple?view=net-5.0)).

When we build a project in VisualStudio that gives the compilation error

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
> Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'IRawElementProviderSimple' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Also we used the namespace `System.Windows.Automation.Provider`, but still gives this error, please give us the proper solution to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to reference the following DLL files:

1. `UIAutomationClient.dll`.
2. `UIAutomationProvider.dll`.

They should be located under:

> %ProgramFiles%\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\5.0.0